# MasterPage Code File the 'inherits' attribute error - ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, master-pages, code-behind, inheritance

I have recently taken over support for an application for a developer who has left our company that use the standard template provided for all of our developers.

When I try to build the application, I get the following error:

> Make sure that the class defined in this code file matches the
>   'inherits' attribute, and that it extends the correct base class (e.g.
>   Page or UserControl).

Here is the source code that is causing the error:

MasterPage mark up

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AppStatic.master.cs" Inherits="AppStatic" %>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class AppStatic : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
```

I have Googled this error message and the solution to to verify the `Inherits` matches that `CodeFile` class name.

Comment: You might want to ascertain the namespace

Comment: The MasterPage does not have a namespace.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: An extremely belated point, more for anyone else who might come across this as I assume Michael has long since solved this and moved on - check that there is not another class named "AppStatic" elsewhere in the solution. This may not be the cause of this specific problem, but I can imagine the symptoms would match.

Comment: My problem was that my markup inherited "System.Web.UI.MasterPage" instead of the codebehind class "MasterPage"